# Final form: revalidate form after validator remove

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I have a form level validator on my fields and setState function to remove it.

```js
const [validator, setValidator] = useState((value) => {...});

<Field
  name="name"
  component={component}
  validator={validator}
  type="string"
/>

<a onClick={() => {setValidator(undefined)}}>Remove validator</a>
```

Problem is that even after validator is removed from the field *form.state.error* still contains error on this field and I cannot submit form.

Is there any way to run revalidation on the field I removed validator from?

I've tried to call *formApi.resetFieldState('name')* right after *setValidator* call but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so *formApi.resetFieldState('name')* works, but it need to be called after *Field* is mounted for it to take effect

https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/621